# They came to you, instead of the king. Because essentially, you are king

Tags: articles

Today I have read this phrase:

> [They came to you, instead of the king. Because essentially, you are king.](https://readsnovelonline.com/con/15179/240.amp#:%7E:text=They%20came%20to%20you%2C%20instead%20of%20the%20king.%20Because%20essentially%2C%20you%20are%20king.)

Why there is "the" here: "They came to you, instead of **the king**". But no "the" here "Because essentially, you are **king**"

The phrase comes from "Words of radiance"

Comment: What is "Words of Radiance"? Who wrote it? Is he even a native English speaker? Questions about the use of the definite and indefinite article in English are generally asked by non-native speakers and should be posted on SE English Language Learners, and not on this site.

Comment: There is a relevant context for a locution like this.  Some countries, including, for example Australia, are democracies and former members of the former British empire and have decided to use the King of Great Britain and Northern Ireland rather than elect a president.  Such countries have a 'High Commissioner' who lives in the country and acts for the King.  So for the purpose this function and only in this context, the High Commissioner of Australia 'is' for the purpose of this role, the King.

Comment: @Tuffy It would work in the UK too, if the "you" here was an *eminence grise* behind the throne. However: that's not the reason for the *the* here. Arseniy shows Poland in his profile: Polish has no articles in the same way as English, so asking the question is not entirely surprising. It does belong on ELL though.

Answer (score 5):

When you use a *title word* --like "king", "boss", "middle manager", etc.-- *to refer to a person*, you need to include "the". But when you use a title *to refer to the title itself*, "the" is optional.

> When I'm **(the) boss**, every desk will have a red Swingline stapler.
> Look busy! **The boss** is coming!
>
> If you work hard, some day you just might become **(the) manager**.
> Pay no attention to **the manager**. He doesn't know how his own department works.

So in your example, the first usage of "king" refers to the actual human who is the king, while the second usage of "king" refers to the title. "You are king" means, "You have the title of 'king'".